# How is virtual system space protected against access?

Tags: windows, security, kernel

On [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces) I read:

> In 64-bit Windows, the theoretical amount of virtual address space is 2^64 bytes (16 exabytes), but only a small portion of the 16-exabyte range is actually used. The 8-terabyte range from 0x000'00000000 through 0x7FF'FFFFFFFF is used for user space, and portions of the 248-terabyte range from 0xFFFF0800'00000000 through 0xFFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF are used for system space.

Since I have 64 bit pointers, I could possibly construct a pointer that points to some 0xFFFFxxxxxxxxxxxx address.

The site continues:

> Code running in user mode has access to user space but does not have access to system space.

If I wereable to guess a valid address in system virtual address space, what mechanism prevents me from writing there?

I know about [memory protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Memory/memory-protection-constants) but that doesn't seem to offer something that distinguishes between user memory and system memory.

Comment: you need read about Paging (x86/x64) and `PTE` format. the Bit 2 (U/S) is the User/Supervisor flag - controls access to the page based on privilege level. If the bit is set, then the page may be accessed by all; if the bit is not set, however, only the kernel mode (0) can access it.

Comment: @RbMm: great. If you cite a bit from some resource, that's enough for me to accept the answer

Comment: look for intel or amd manuals - paging. or in brief - [Paging](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) or http://cs.hadassah.ac.il/staff/martin/Micro_Modern/slide03.pdf

Comment: [`HARDWARE_PTE`](http://librecrops.github.io/lost-sdk/files/HARDWARE_PTE.h.html) - if `Owner == 1`  user mode (privilege level 3 by cpu view) can access page (of couse `Valid` must be set). otherwise cpu generate exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments by [@RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm), this information is stored in the PTE (page table entry). There seems to be a bit which defines whether access is granted from user mode.

This is confirmed by [an article on OSR online](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm%5eid=60.htm), which says

> Bit Name: User access

The structure itself does not seem to be part of Microsoft symbols

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_page*
          ntdll!_PAGED_LOOKASIDE_LIST
          ntdll!_PAGEFAULT_HISTORY
0:000> dt ntdll!page*
0:000> dt ntdll!*pte*
00007fff324fe910  ntdll!RtlpTestHookInitialize
```

The PTEs are closely supported by the CPU (the MMU, memory management unit, specifically). That's why we find additional information [at OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging), which says

> U, the 'User/Supervisor' bit, controls access to the page based on privilege level. If the bit is set, then the page may be accessed by all; if the bit is not set, however, only the supervisor can access it.

In some [leaked SDK files](http://librecrops.github.io/lost-sdk/files/HARDWARE_PTE.h.html), the bit seems to be

> `unsigned __int64 Owner : 1;`

Since the PTE is supported by the CPU, we should find similar things in Linux. And voilà, I see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1442149/480982) which also has the bit:

> `#define _PAGE_USER  0x004`

which exactly matches the information of OSDev.